# Swipe animation during back/forward navigation? Where is it?

Tags: browser

I've come to heavily rely on Safari's back/forward animation, which allows me to not only navigate quickly between visited pages, but also reveals the content of the previous/next page while on the current page without refreshing, thus greatly facilitating comparisons and plain-old reading. Once you experience this, there is really no going back -- it's like reading a book.

It is shocking to me Google have still (v4.3) not implemented this fantastic memory-aid and usability feature in Chrome. Since no other Android browser I tried (Dolphin, Opera, Firefox & Puffin) has such gestures by default, is it at all possible to have swipe navigation/animation on Android?

Comment: There are [tons of browser apps for Android](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=browser&c=apps). Maybe you should keep trying. Is it possible? Probably. A developer just has to see the need for it.

Comment: Give a try to [Opera mini](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.opera.mini.android). I think you will find similar navigation in it too.

Comment: Opera mini does provide on-screen back/forward buttons and going through history is fast, but there is still no swipe navigation. UC Browser Mini is the only popular browser I've found to do this even though not very smoothly.

Answer (score 1):

UC Browser is the only popular Android browser I've found to support swipe navigation (i.e. one-finger dragging from left or right side slides to previous/next page without refreshing). Swiping only works adequately in fit-to-screen mode, but even though it's not as smooth as Safari, it does the job. :)